# required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm using spring boot, apache kafka.

[image]

Below is my controller code

```
package com.infy.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/serving/")
public class ServingRequestWebControllerImpl implements ServingRequestWebController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServingRequestWebControllerImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, TaskDetailsEntity> kafkaJsontemplate;

    String TOPIC_NAME = "sample-topic";

    @Override
    @PostMapping(value = "/produce", consumes = { "application/json" }, produces = { "application/json" })
    public String taskQueue(TaskDetailsEntity taskgDetailsEntity) {
        kafkaJsontemplate.send(TOPIC_NAME, taskgDetailsEntity);
        return "Serving Request Published Successfully To:- " + TOPIC_NAME;
    }
}
```

Below is the Kafka configuration code

```
package com.infy.config;
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, String>(producerFactory());
    }

    public ProducerFactory<String, ServingDetailsEntity> producerFactoryServingDetail() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, ServingDetailsEntity> kafkaTemplateServingDetailsListener() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, ServingDetailsEntity>(producerFactoryServingDetail());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, ServingDetailsEntity> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "event-group");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(ServingDetailsEntity.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ServingDetailsEntity> kafkaTemplateTaskDetailsListener() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ServingDetailsEntity> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ServingDetailsEntity>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Below is my Consumer code

```
package com.infy.consumer;
@Service
public class KafkaConsumerService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumerService.class);

    @Autowired
    private ServingService service;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "sample-topic", groupId = "event-group",containerFactory = "kafkaTemplateTaskDetailsListener")
    public void consumeTask(TaskDetailsEntity taskDtls){
        System.out.println("Consumed Message:- \n "+taskDtls);

        TaskDetailsEntity upsert = service.taskUpsert(taskDtls);
        System.out.println(upsert.getId());
        logger.info("\n Exit KafkaConsumerService consumeTask");
    }
}
```

when i run my spring boot application i'm getting below error

**Description:
Field kafkaJsontemplate in com.infy.controller.ServingRequestWebControllerImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'kafkaTemplate' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because auto-configuration 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' was excluded
Action:
Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' in your configuration.**

i tried by adding below configuration to application.properties, but no luck

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
```

below is my spring boot main code

```
package com.infy;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootInitializer.class, args);
    }
}
```

please someone help me, what mistake i have done.

Comment: Could you also mention the package in the above classes and also can you show you main application class along with package name.

Comment: @GauravDhiman question edited

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of that exact problem, but if you want your listeners to work you will need an EnableKafka annotation. That may be the problem - to be honest I can't remember if it is required for the producer side of things.

Comment: Probably put it on your KafkaConfig class

Comment: I also notice that you are trying to autowire a KafkaTemplate for TaskDetailsEntity values but in your configuration you are declaring a KafkaTemplate bean for ServingDetailsEntity values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to auto-wire a bean of type `KafkaTemplate<String, TaskDetailsEntity>`,
but you only declared beans of type `KafkaTemplate<String, String>` and `KafkaTemplate<String, ServingDetailsEntity>` in your KafkaConfig.

Probably also a mistake that `producerFactory()` has `@Bean` annotation and `producerFactoryServingDetail()` has not.